# Detect when cookies are changed manually by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

**Detect when user changes cookies manually or by some cookie editor**
1. Without page reloading
2. Without setting intervals
And fire an event or function
**Like Facebook**, when you changes your some specific cookie values

Comment: Can't be done, there is no event for changing cookies, and without regularly checking the cookie there's no way to do it.

Comment: But facebook is doing successfully. Please, check it out!